# Customize the display of a widget in a sidebar [wordpress]

Tags: wordpress

Currently during the sidebar registration we can mention "before_widget" and "after_widget". But this limit the extent we can wrap the widgets.

Is there a way I can display the widgets in any manner I want to, within a sidebar

e.g

```
<?php foreach($widgets as $widget): ?>
   <div>
    <h1>heading</h1>
    <p>details</p>
    <?=widget->show()?>
   </div> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to make it clear in your title and question that this is in regard to **wordpress**. IMHO, PHP shouldn't even be tagged, because the question and solution are specific to a wordpress, a subset of PHP.

Comment: Thanks, removed the tag and changed the title.